# How to programmatically clear a google-composer TASK?

Tags: task, command-line-interface, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I'm using a DAG that dynamically creates a task: everytime I create a new task in the DAG I'd like to clear  another task in the same DAG, is it possible?

We've not found any API that supports clearing task, are we missing anything?

We're trying using airflow CLI, but seems impossible to clear a task identified by 
a specific "Execution Date", is there another option?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use `airflow clear` cli command to achieve that.

```
airflow clear [-h] [-t TASK_REGEX] [-s START_DATE] [-e END_DATE] [-sd SUBDIR]
              [-u] [-d] [-c] [-f] [-r] [-x] [-dx]
              dag_id
```

Documentation: https://airflow.apache.org/cli.html#clear

Comment: Thanks Kaxil, we already tried with the clear command but we have multiple execution in the same day and we don't know how to clear a specific task execution, we'd like to clear just the **task instance** of the last **execution date**.

Comment: We can pass a TASK_REGEX and the START_DATE and END_DATE can have Datetime format.

Comment: So if I could get a list of execution dates I could arrange a time interval containing only the task I would clear, is there a way to get the list of execution dates for a specified task?

Answer (score 0):

You can clear task states with this command in composer:
`gcloud composer environments run <environment> --location=asia-northeast1 clear -- <DAG_ID> -c -s <dag run start date> -e <dag run end date> --upstream --downstream`